# Is watching videos online that were uploaded illegally counted as causing others to sin?

Tags: halacha, internet, gezel-stealing, lifnei-iver

Some poskim hold that watching videos online that were uploaded illegally is not considered gezel, only if one himself uploaded the video it would be gezel. However, if someone watched the videos would it be counted as causing others to sin since you are giving more views to the uploader and thus he would be encouraged to upload more videos illegally?

Comment: Your question would be more interesting to me and, I suspect, to many others, if it included a citation for the claim in its first sentence. Not that it's a bad question as is, though; +1.